# Is it possible to distribute an app without going through the App Store?

Tags: ios-appstore

I have heard that it's possible to distribute an app on the iPhone without going through the Apple App Store. I'm dubious, but thought I'd check.

Is this possible?

Comment: Where did you hear this. Ask them for evidence.

Comment: Not unless you are restricting yourself to just jailbrken phones, so no.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible. It is not as easy as the App Store, and it does come with some drawbacks. Contrary to the comments here, it does not mean that you have to have a jailbroken phone though.

Take a look at for example the popular project "AltStore":

https://altstore.io

Answer (score 0):

Developers can run their own code on their iPhones. The functionality behind this is essentially also used by the AltStore. (Here is an interesting explanation: http://rileytestut.com/blog/2019/09/25/introducing-altstore/)

There is TestFlight, which is offered by Apple. The idea is that developers can test their beta versions with a limited number of users. Although apps have to be submitted to Apple and they have to meet certain criteria, the review process is not as strict as for the App Store.

Companies and other institutions can use Apple Business Manager. However, the apps also have to go through review by Apple:

> Develop custom apps for private distribution. Meet the unique needs of
> businesses by privately offering apps you’ve customized just for them.
> Specific businesses who you identify in App Store Connect will see
> your app and be able to purchase it in the Content section of Apple
> Business Manager. Custom app distribution works well if you’re
> distributing apps to specific partners, clients, or franchisees. You
> can also use custom app distribution for your internal employees.
> Businesses can distribute and manage purchased apps through Mobile
> Device Management. Alternatively, businesses can choose to provide
> redemption codes to authorized users. If you’ve been contracted to
> deliver a custom version of your app to a business, distributing a
> custom app allows you to maintain the code and retain your
> intellectual property rights. (Source: https://developer.apple.com/business/distribute/)